# Ambiguity with classes in two different packages, why compiler doesn't complain?

Tags: java

When two different packages have imported and they have both a same named class, and client program make non fully qualified reference to that **ambiguous** named class, there will be compiler error that says "**Reference** to *'something'* is **ambiguous**" (*'something'* is the **ambiguous class name**).
But what happens when we've imported a foreign package in our package that have a same named class with the imported package, is strange! **Compiler does not complain** there is an ambiguous situation, why?

For example, suppose there are :

1)package packa that contains Chocolate.java and Test.java:

```
//Test.java in packa
package packa;

import packb.*;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
                System.out.println("in main() in packa.Test!");

        new Chocolate() . doSth();
    }
    
}

//Chocolate.java in packa
package packa;

public class Chocolate {
        
        public void doSth(){
                System.out.println("Chocolate in Packa!");
        }
        
}
```

2)package packb that contains another Chocolate.java:

```
//Chocolate.java in packb
package packb;

public class Chocolate {
        
        public void doSth(){
                System.out.println("Chocolate in Packb!");
        }
        
}
```

3)a default package that contains TestAll.java:

```
//TestAll.java

import packa.*;
import packb.*;
public class TestAll {
    public static void main(String[] args){
                System.out.println("in main() in TestAll!");

        new Chocolate() . doSth();
    }
    
}
```

As it can been seen, by running TestAll.java compiler issues:

> ```
> TestAll.java:8: error: reference to Chocolate is ambiguous
>       new Chocolate() . doSth();
>           ^
>   both class packb.Chocolate in packb and class packa.Chocolate in packa match
> 1 error
> ```

That is tangable, but by running packa.Test, it sees only its Chocolate not other and prints:

> in main() in packa.Test!
>
> Chocolate in Packa!

Comment: I *suspect* that if you import `packb.Chocolate` instead of `packb.*`, that will make a difference. I expect JLS 6.4.1 is relevant here: "A type-import-on-demand declaration never causes any other declaration to be shadowed." But it's been a while since I've tried to read the JLS forensically, so I'm only leaving this as an avenue for further work rather than an answer...